# What does "trail a plan" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning, verbs

The Fed needs both wage and price growth to cool if it is to hit its 2% inflation target. It is expected to raise short-term interest rates, which started the year below 0.25%, to over 2.5% by December, and to continue to raise rates above 3% in 2023. This week the central bank **trailed a plan** to shrink its $8.5trn bond holdings, starting in May, at a much faster pace than during the last period of “quantitative tightening”.

Comment: Could it be [trail](https://www.lexico.com/definition/trail)? "3 Give advance publicity to (a film, broadcast, or proposal) *'The bank's plans have been extensively trailed'*." It says "starting in May" which supports this meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on the use of "trail" in movies, in which a "trailer" is a short film that advertises, previews or promotes a film (the metaphor is from a small object that is pulled along behind a vehicle, but movie trailers typically come *before* the main film)

So to "trail" something means to give a preview of your ideas.  In this case it means that the Fed(eral  bank) is informally suggesting this plan, to hear what economists and politicians think about it, before formally proposing it.

> At the office, Jim trailed his idea of getting rid of desktop computers and giving everyone a tablet. Mary thought it was an interesting idea, but Jill from Finance was against it, and so it probably won't happen.